# Can not locate AWS login page' s mail adress box

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, css-selectors

I am trying to locate email input box of AWS login page. I tried css selector and xpath but selenium still can not locate the element.

My css selector is,

```
#resolver_container > div > input
```

My code is,

```
WebElement emailBox = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#resolver_container > div > input"));
   emailBox.sendKeys(email);
```

Error is,

> Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"#resolver_container > div > input"}
>     (Session info: chrome=78.0.3904.108)

Link is,

[AWS Login Page](https://signin.aws.amazon.com/signin?redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fconsole.aws.amazon.com%2Fconsole%2Fhome%3Fstate%3DhashArgs%2523%26isauthcode%3Dtrue&client_id=arn%3Aaws%3Aiam%3A%3A015428540659%3Auser%2Fhomepage&forceMobileApp=0)

Comment: Code trials and error stack trace please ...

Comment: I edit my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Selenium executes the code too fast. So by the time your element is available to use, the selenium has started searching for the same. That's why you are getting this exception. Just add some wait. It'll work.

Answer (score 0):

I have just successfully tried with the following selecter

```
#resolving_input.aws-signin-textfield
```

Can you please try that.

Comment: There is no problem when I search in the browser console but selenium says I cant find it. By the way I tried your selector but it gives same exception.

Answer (score 0):

Your locator not wrong, it seem like you need wait. Use `WebDriverWait`:

```
WebElement emailBox = new WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.cssSelector("#resolver_container > div > input")));
emailBox.sendKeys(email);
```

Following import:

```
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
```

You can also use `id`:

```
By.id("resolving_input")
```